# HasPanelShield trait not seems to trigger created event on user laravel filament

Tags: laravel-filament

I have a clean User model implementing HasPanelShield, upon the creation it doesn't seem to assign
the user_panel role. am i missing something? I've modified just the role name.

```
'panel_user' => [
        'name' => 'staff',
        'enabled' => true,
    ],
```

And added the trait to the user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements FilamentUser
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;
    use HasPanelShield;
    use HasEvents;
```